# shell - how to match a hyphen (-) or nothing using regex

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
versionA=0.3.4 
if [[ $versionA = +([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
    echo "version is compliant"
else
    echo "Version is not compliant to sem ver standard use this format instead x.y.z"
fi
```

I am checking if version is compliant or not using this script, The part that is stumping is this `versionA=0.3.5-7.1.0-7` it's also compliant and I need to use regex that match a hyphen or nothing and other last part : `if [[ $versionA = +([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]])[-]* ]]` this doesn't work and consider `3.4.4` not compliant `<br>` and I want to consider all `x.y.z` and `x.y.z-whatever` compliant the important thing is to have the three first part and they are integer `! <br>`
any hints please ?

Comment: You may want to add more test examples for pass/fail cases.

Comment: That's not a regular expression; it's an extended pattern.

Comment: What is the true condition for this string `versionA=0.3.5-7.1.0-7` comparison? When will you say version is compliance?

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match x.y.z and x.y.z-whatever with grep: `grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-.+)?$'`

```
for v in 1.2 3.4.5 6.7.8-whatever 9.0.1-; do
    if echo "$v" | grep -Eq '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-.+)?$'; then
        echo "$v: ok"
    else
        echo "$v: not ok"
    fi
done

1.2: not ok
3.4.5: ok
6.7.8-whatever: ok
9.0.1-: not ok
```

Explanation:

- `[0-9]`: a digit
- `+`: at least one, or more
- `\.`: a literal dot (`.`)
- `()`: a group
- `?`: optional, so `()?` makes everything in the parentheses optional
- `-`: a literal hyphen `-`
- `.+`: at least one character (whatever which one)
- `$`: end of the string, so there must be nothing after that

Comment: this doesn't fail when i have version=2.4 i i want to test first if there is three digit x.y.z and if there is - x.y.z-whatever it will pass too, how to make the hyphen optional so that x.y.z pass and also x.y.z-whatever

Comment: `echo '2.4' | grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-.*)?'` returns nothing in my shell. So `2.4` should not be matched.